# GPL attribution for programs that come with Ubuntu

Tags: license, legal, gpl

I'm sorry if this has already been asked or made clear in documentation, but I couldn't find an answer to this.

I am using an Ubuntu server to run a program and my program has a licensing page where I do the attributions required by the licenses of the programs I have installed. By default, Ubuntu has many programs installed and I want to know if I can just do the attribution for Ubuntu or if I need to specifically acknowledge the  dozens of programs individually.

Does anyone know if this is officially spelled out somewhere? Or maybe if there is some unofficial but generally accepted practice?

I want to give credit where credit it due, but I also feel like listing every single program that makes up Ubuntu seems like overkill. I am of course listing the programs I installed myself, this question is only focused on the ones that come with it when Ubuntu is installed. Thank you for your help!